# HTTP health check using AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS environment that seems to lose connectivity to a server we are connected to via a static route. I want to be able to monitor the situation by sending an HTTP GET request to this remote server. Is this possible using CloudWatch? I am new to AWS and I have not found anything on this topic. My guess is that I am using the wrong lingo. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Route53 health check on HTTP or TCP, you don't need to use Route53 as DNS service, you can simply use Health check service and trigger lambda/Cloudwatch/SNS etc.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-types.html